# c++ template specialization in circular queue

Tags: c++, stl, circular-buffer

Hi i am tryng to develop a circular queue, but this implementation works fine for basics type like int float and so on,

```
template<typename R, size_t aSize=200>
class CircularQueue{
public:

    explicit CircularQueue(const R & aElement);


    ~CircularQueue()
    {

    }

    bool push(const R & aElement);

    bool pop(R & aElement);

    bool isEmpty() const    ;

    bool isFull() const     ;
private:
    CircularQueue(){}
    CircularQueue(const CircularQueue &);
    const CircularQueue & operator=(const CircularQueue &);
    int incrementar(int  ) const;
        static const size_t capacity=aSize+1;
        R array[capacity];
        volatile int tail;
        volatile int head;

};
```

but when i try to speciallized this to a custom type the compiler tells that i have to call the especif constructor:
 Especif class

```
    class PutMessage: public  IMetodo, Sujeto<PutMessage>
    {
    public:
       explicit PutMessage(Servant * aServant = 0,Mensaje * aMensaje=0, Observer<PutMessage> * aFuture=0);
        virtual ~PutMessage();
    bool guard() const;
    int getResult() const ;
    void call();

    Mensaje * getMensaje() const;

    Servant * getServant() const;

    bool hasFuture() const;
    private:
    PutMessage();
    Servant * mServant;
    Mensaje * mMensaje;
    int mResult;
    bool mHasFuture;
};
}
```

the call to the circular queue:

```
CircularQueue<PutMessage,32> aCircular(*aMessageQueue);
```

Do i have to reimplement the class to a semispecialization class??

Comment: Looks like this class is storing its contents by value which means PutMessage would have to have a public copy constructor etc. - should you be storing pointers instead i.e. CircularQueue<PutMessage*, 32>

Comment: you r write, i will have to reimplement that part to a array on the heap, perhaps that it causing that the compiler it is calling the constructor,

Comment: @PeterHull or specify a move constructor or `emplace_back(...)`.  For the record, `std::vector` uses copy and move constructors as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by this data member:

```
R array[capacity];
```

An array already contains all its elements, and so a call to `R`'s constructor is required for each one. Why not use `std::vector` instead?

Comment: the problem is it been causing because of that array declaring in the stack, i have rewrite it on the heap taking only pointers, but i dont think using a std::vector would be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Stop using the `explicit` keyword in the way shown in your code.  In your `PutMessage` class, make a void constructor and it should work fine:

`PutMessage() : PutMessage(0,0,0) {}`

For the record, assign invalid pointers to `nullptr` instead of 0.

Edit:  Although, for a better implementation of `CircularQueue`, you should really use `operator new()` to assign your queue space and placement new to construct the elements.  However, there might be some design requirement that specifies using the stack instead, which is why this is not part of my original answer.

Comment: Explicit should only be used when compiler implicit conversions can actually screw up your code imo.  In your functions, you have pointers as parameters, which will not be implicitly converted by the compiler so it is redundant anyway.  Additionally, I would venture to say your `volatile` is somewhat redundant here as well.  As a side note, I wasn't really thinking when I put my answer down, and the current `PutMessage` constructor should work fine as a void constructor.  I'm not totally sure what the problem was anymore (making an array of R should have worked methinks).

Comment: OHHH I see it now!  Hidden in the `private` section of `PutMessage`, there was already a void constructor!  Totally missed that.  `CircularQueue` couldn't construct the array because the void constructor was private.